# Curly braces in variable names

Tags: c++, naming, folly

Lately I've been browsing through some code of facebooks folly library and saw a variable named like

```
HTTPServer* const server_{nullptr};
```

as a class member.
I've never seen something like this before and wondered if there is any special meaning. Googling only made me found other examples like this one in boost code to.

Maybe someone has an explanation.

Comment: The short answer is that you can read the above line as `HTTPServer* const server_ = nullptr;`

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that short version.

Comment: You're welcome! The above does look a bit strange though. Since the pointer is `const` and initialized to `nullptr` it will not be possible to change it to point at a `HTTPServer` instance later.

Comment: There is a constructor which can be used to intialize it to something else. This way it makes sense.

Comment: That would be applicable if an `HTTPServer` was instantiated. I don't see that happening here. It's initializing the pointer no matter if `HTTPServer` has a constructor that accepts a `nullptr` or not.

Comment: No, I mean that the class having the pointer to HTTPServer as a class member has a constructor initializing it.

Comment: Aha, yes, that would work. `class Carrier { Carrier() : server_(new HTTPServer) {} ...` would override the default initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used as an initializer list. In your case, `HTTPServer` pointer would be set to `nullptr`, but you can use curly braces even with plain types such as `int`, `float`, etc.

Its role is to initialize the variable with value(s) inside, which means that both attitudes below mean the same:

```c
int x = 10; 
int x{10};
```

You can also initialize arrays in much simpler way:

```c
int x[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

instead of using:

```c
x[0] = 1;
x[1] = 2;
x[2] = 3;
x[3] = 4;
x[4] = 5;
```

If you wish, you can also use

```c
int x{};
```

to initialize `x` with the value of 0.

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know about this short version. :) Now it's clear!

Comment: If it is all you wanted to know, mark the question as answered - other people will know that you no longer need help with that topic.

Comment: I already did so. Just had to wait for the time limit to go over.